Do we need a notion of the center of mass in special relativity?
I don't see much mention of the center of mass in discussions of special relativity. I understand that there is a definition for it, but it is relatively obscure and seems to depend on mass-energy equivalence. However, I find both its obscurity and its reliance on mass-energy equivalence to be worrying, for reasons I will explain.
Starting with its obscurity. In Newtonian physics, we often like to refer to the "position" of extended bodies. We can do this naturally by referring to the location of its center of mass. This allows us to describe things like the velocity/acceleration/trajectory of extended objects. Without a clear notion of center of mass, it seems futile to even talk about "where" extended objects are located and consequently what trajectories they follow.
Next with its reliance on mass-energy. I'm referencing the answer posted at the below link, since I'm still searching for the papers the answerer linked: Is the center of mass in general relativity equal to the center of mass in newtonian gravity?
With my (admittedly still developing) understanding of relativistic dynamics, it seems that we can attribute the increase in mass of, say, a thermally excited object to the increase in difficulty it takes to change the velocities of the individual particles that make it up, due to their higher individual momenta as well as momentum's nonlinear scaling with velocity. But unless we can even understand what it means to talk about the position of an object, how can we pin down this concept rigorously? We can't talk about how difficult it is to accelerate that object, and hence it seems difficult to even talk about its mass, let alone how it relates to energy; so then how can we even say that $E=mc^2$ even applies for extended objects? I mean, we could assume energy conservation and take, say, Einstein's derivation, but it seems like we should justify that energy conservation even still works in relativity.
Apologies if my question demonstrates a bit of a misunderstanding; I suppose that is what I am trying to clear up here.

I don't really understand your question, but I can give you an example. Energy is not a Lorentz invariant quantity. However, the center of mass energy of a collision (which could be relativistic) is in fact Lorentz invariant.

Sorry for the confusion. My question is whether a definition of center of mass is necessary in relativity. To me it seems like we are skipping something important when discussing extended objects if we don't define it. I haven't seen a concrete definition for it either, as I am still trying to find the first of the two papers that were mentioned in the question I linked.

I think that I get confused when I hear talk about how the mass of a system increases if its energy increases while its momentum remains constant. It seems like it's saying that, somehow, the energy of the particles that make up the whole system cause the total system to be harder to accelerate. If this is true, then I need to get a better understanding about what is meant by "accelerating" an extended object, which seems to not make sense without a clear picture of what "position" means for an extended object.
